# Compare class __NSCFDictionary

Tags: objective-c, class, compare, nsdictionary, nsobject

Could someone explain why I get 0, instead of 1 ??

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    if (item != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[item class]);
        NSLog(@"%d",[[item class]isEqual:[NSDictionary class]]);
    };
}

__NSCFDictionary 0
```

---

Regards, Darek :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get 0 because __NSCFDictionary isn't the same as NSDictionary.

Try using `isKindOfClass:` instead.